# How to resolve user registration and activation email error in Django registration?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

So I was just trying to setup a basic user authentication in Django and downloaded a django registration app with templates. Now when I run the server at 127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/register/ I get a basic registration page, I fill in the details and when I click submit I get this error "NoReverseMatch at /accounts/register/"

```
Error during template rendering
In template Users/sudhasinha/mysite/mysite/registration/templates/registration/activation_email.txt,   error at line 4
'url' requires a non-empty first argument. The syntax changed in Django 1.5, see the docs.
1   {% load i18n %}
2   {% trans "Activate account at" %} {{ site.name }}:
3   
4   http://{{ site.domain }}{**% url registration_activate activation_key %**}
5   
6   {% blocktrans %}Link is valid for {{ expiration_days }} days.{% endblocktrans %}
7
```

---

This is what my activation_email.txt looks like:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% trans "Activate account at" %} {{ site.name }}:

http://{{ site.domain }}{% url registration_activate activation_key %}

{% blocktrans %}Link is valid for {{ expiration_days }} days.{% endblocktrans %}
```

---

And this is what my registration_form.html looks like:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post" action=".">
{{ form.as_p }}

<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Submit' %}" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

I have very minimal experience with Django and would appreciate some help to resolve this error. My urls seem to be setup correctly but I will post it if needed. Also pardon my horrible formatting

Comment: you are providing an empty authencation_key, based on your error report. Update the OP with the view related and possibly what's that "django authentication app" you're using

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, the behavior of the template `url` tag changed in Django 1.5.  It used to take only plain text as the view name, so it didn't have to be quoted.  It's useful to be able to pass in view names as context variables, so the syntax changed.  The docs describing this change say:

> In Django 1.5, the behavior of the url template tag will change, with the first argument being made into a context variable, rather than being a special case unquoted constant. This will allow the url tag to use a context variable as the value of the URL name to be reversed.
>   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#url

You can still just use a string constant if you quote it appropriately, though - your email template should look like this:

```
http://{{ site.domain }}{% url "registration_activate" activation_key %}
```